# Indexeddb search on multiple columns using mysql LIKE

Tags: indexeddb

I am developing a PWA and I have a database that I would like to query like so:

`SELECT * FROM plants WHERE (plant_genus LIKE 'Ab%') AND (plant_species LIKE 'pr%')`

Index is defined as such:

`surveyPlantsOS.createIndex("multiple", ['plant_genus', 'plant_species', 'occurrence'], { unique: false });`

I have tried the following:

`const midRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(['Ab','pr'], ['Ab'+'\uffff','pr'+'\uffff']);`
`let cursor = await dbTT.getAllFromIndex('tt_survey_plants', 'multiple', midRange)`

This works fine on the first column, but the second column is ignored.

I would like the 'Ab' to search on the 'plant_genus' column and the 'pr' to search on the 'plant_species' column

Any help would be much appreciated.

For the time being I have resolved this issue by parsing the result set this way:

```
  if (cursor) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(cursor)) {
      if (arrChars.length > 1) {
        if (value.plant_species.indexOf(arrChars[1]) != -1) {
          //console.log('found ', `${value.plant_genus} ${value.plant_species} `)
          data[value.plant_genus+' '+value.plant_species] = null    
        }
      }
      else
        data[value.plant_genus+' '+value.plant_species] = null
    }
  }
```